# 2010 toyota tacoma AC not working

Tags: electrical, toyota, ac, truck, tacoma

Blower motor is brand new, tried a replacement just in case and it still did not work. I've got a new diffuser on the wire harness. Lights come on for the ac when I turn the knob on the dash, but the blower wont start. I'm looking at the mag clutch relay. Not sure how to check if it's working. Other relays in the fuse box look different. Any suggestions? Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Other than the two being parts of the same system. The blower motor not working has nothing to do with the magnetic clutch. Check for power and ground at the blower motor. Which are you missing? And what are the respective measurements?

Comment: 1.8 ohms at the blower motor. Around 4 volts. It's a 12 volt motor. Bith while on high. Diffuser seems to be working.